# sorting using comparable java

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I'm trying to sort an array of records. But I get "not a Record" error. The method getCt() is in a different class, the program compiles and the array is of the record type. I really don't know what is wrong with this code.

HashTable:

```
public class HashTable {
    private Record [] array;
    private int size;
    private int indexSize=0;
    private boolean updated,found;

    public HashTable(int m){
        array= new Record[m];
        size=0;
    }

    public void getCt() {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        // return array[0];
    }
```

Record class:

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.*;

public class Record implements Comparable {
    private Integer count;
    private DNSkey key;

    public Record(DNSkey key) {
        this.key = key;
        count = 1;
    }

    public void update() {
        count++;
    }

    public DNSkey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Record)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Not a Record");
        }
        Record check = (Record) obj;
        return getCount().compareTo(check.getCount());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getKey() + " " + getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how do you initialize your array?

Comment: Where is the `array` declared and initialised?

Comment: Just as a side note, homework tag is obsolete

Comment: **array** initialization is not shown

Comment: Ok, and where do you add elements to the array?

Comment: I voted to close as it seems the OP does not want to provide necessary information (code showing how the array is filled).

Answer (score 3):

one easy way is to use generics :

```
public class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
```

...

```
public int compareTo(Record check){
    return getCount().compareTo(check.getCount());
}
```

Comment: public class Record implements Comparable<Record> doesnt work

Comment: it should work, what is the version of java SDK you are using?

Comment: it does if your Java is 1.5 or later.

Comment: yes, you have to implement `@Override public int compareTo(final @Nullable Record check)` then (instead of the `Object` parameter type.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be null items in the array. "null instanceof Class" will return false.

This will throw the Exception:

```
Record[] array = new Record[] { new Record(...), null };
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Comment: in this case, adding **if(obj==null) return 1;** should fix it

Answer (score -2):

Use generics! And an @Override annotation.